# How to delete a ListView document from Firestore in Android when I click it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanna delete a document from firestore and I wanna change the activity when I click to the listView item. I can change the activity and I can remove the movie when I click it but I open the app again it's still in there cause I can't delete it from firestore I try but I couldn't do it. How can I do that?

[image]

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            filmArray.remove(position);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Intent intent=new Intent(IzlemekIstediklerim.this,FilmEkle.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: filmArray.remove(position) removes it from the list but not from db

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#java_1, have a look at this

Comment: When you perform the delete operation, you also want to delete the movie from the database? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo yes I also want to delete it from database

Comment: In this case, please edit your question and add the code that is related to the delete operation and tell what it doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: I also think this article, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) might help.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) you have to access collection then remove it

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            filmArray.remove(position);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            deleteFromDB();

            Intent intent=new Intent(IzlemekIstediklerim.this,FilmEkle.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

delete function

```
private void deleteFromDB(){
db.collection("movies").document("Inception")
        .delete()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this may be helpful :

```
      private final FireBaseFireStore db;

       public void deleteDocument() {
    // [START delete_document]
    db.collection("movies").document("inception")
            .delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
                }
            });
    // [END delete_document]
}
```

take a look [at this github project](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/b239f4c3e41a0e6e678bcff909587d9b8a63abcb/firestore/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/firestore/DocSnippets.java#L508-L521)